# Register of the expression "l'heure n'est pas au farniente"

Tags: expressions, registre

I'm translating some colloquial English sentences into French:

> **L'heure** / **Le temps** / **Le moment n'est pas au farniente**, mais le client, comme qui dirait, ayant toujours raison, si tu veux te reposer un peu, qui suis-je pour t’en empêcher ?

... and I wonder if "l'heure n'est pas au farniente" belongs to the same register as the original English phrasing "this is no time to slack off"?

Answer (score 1):

- "L'heure n'est pas au farniente" is the best proposal.
- "Le moment n'est pas au farniente" is acceptable
- "Le temps n'est pas au farniente" is weird, because, it sounds like "The weather is no time to slack off"

The more fluent sentence (maybe spoken french) would be:
**Ce n'est pas le moment de se laisser aller, mais comme on dit : "le client est roi", alors si tu veux te reposer, vas-y !**

For a more formal translation, I need the complete original sentence.

Comment: Yes, your rephrasing sounds better. *Farniente* is slightly literary, not colloquial as I guess *slack-off* is.

Comment: @jlliagre The original English sentences come from dialogues in a novel. Do you still think *Farniente* is a bit too literary? I wanted to give them some flavour.

Comment: Yes, *farniente* is "sophisticated" spoken French.